# Issue with python-docx, style parameter returning error

Tags: debugging, error-handling, valueerror, python-docx

I am trying to create the beginning of an automated word document and I keep getting an odd error that I cannot make sense of. I am a novice programmer so the solution could be more simple and I am overlooking something but this is the code:

```
# create body
p = document.add_paragraph('April 22, 2015\n\n', style = 'Body Text')
p.add_run('VIA REGULAR MAIL\n\n', style = 'Body Text').bold['True'].underline['True']
```

This returns this ValueError
`ValueError: assigned style is type PARAGRAPH (1), need type CHARACTER (2)`

I tried to set style = 'CHARACTER' and 'CHARACTER (2)' but that did not work either

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that you are trying to apply a paragraph style to a character (run) level of text. Styles in python-docx are divided into two main types: Paragraph styles and Character styles.

Paragraph styles apply to entire paragraphs and determine attributes like alignment, indentation, and spacing. Character styles, on the other hand, apply to individual or runs of characters within a paragraph and determine attributes like font, size, and color.

To apply a bold and underline formatting, you don't need to use a character style, you can use attributes of the Run object. You should be able to just call .bold = True and .underline = True directly on the Run object returned by add_run. Here is how to do it:

Try this code once.

```
p = document.add_paragraph('April 22, 2015\n\n', style='Body Text')
run = p.add_run('VIA REGULAR MAIL\n\n')
run.bold = True
run.underline = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The mismatch in style type you are attempting to apply to the run object in Python's docx library is the cause of the error you are seeing. By using p.add_run(...), you are assigning a paragraph style ('Body Text') to an object called run, which is expecting a character style. This is why there is a ValueError.

Applying the paragraph style to the paragraph and only character-level formatting (bold and underlining) to the run will resolve this problem. This is how you change your code:

```
#paragraph with paragraph style
p = document.add_paragraph('April 22, 2015\n\n', style='Body Text')

# Add a run to the paragraph and apply character-level formatting
run = p.add_run('VIA REGULAR MAIL\n\n')
run.bold = True
run.underline = True
```